# linux bash vs ./ loop error

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, cron

I have a script that has a loop with this basic code:

```
while read -r line
do
    ...
done < <(rsync --list-only  --rsync-path='sudo rsync' [sftploginandpath]);
```

It works great when I test it, calling it as ./myScript.sh

But it errors when I run it with bash myScript.sh or sh myScript.sh, I need to put it in my crontab as sh myScript,  I have another script with the same basic loop call, being called bash goodScript.sh that doesn't error, so I've got no idea what's going on.

The error I'm getting is:

```
myScript.sh: line 42: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
myScript.sh: line 42: `done < <(rsync --list-only  --rsync-path='sudo rsync' [sftploginandpath]); '
```

Any advice would be great, thanks.

Comment: what does your shebang look like? sh != bash

Comment: That error is expected with `sh myScript.sh` but not with `bash myScript.sh`. Can you confirm that you're getting that error with `bash myScript.sh`?

Comment: It's just #!/bin/bash, and it just started working in bash, not sure why, but still bad in sh, I guess I'll just update my cron to call it with bash instead.

Comment: So just to elucidate, `<(cmd)` is a Bashism, and not portable to other shells (including Bash itself when invoked as `sh`).